# Evaluate value just once

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I change the code without the help of let that (g x) is just evaluated once?

```
(define f 
  (lambda (x)
      (i (g x) (h (g x)))))
```

Comment: Why "without the help of `let`"? Are you in a language that doesn't have `let`, such as BSL? Or is there another constraint from a homework assignment or something?

Comment: We were not allowed to use let due to our homework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the solution with the `let`, then transform it using the following equivalence between `let` and `lambda`:

```
(let ((name expression1))
   expression2)

==

((lambda (name) expression2) expression1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If let is not allowed, I would use `define` inside the `define`:

```
(define f 
  (lambda (x)
    (define y (g x))
    (i y (h y))))
```

However, I guess the other answer is the desired one. Because it uses the almighty `lambda` :) .

Comment: When you use internal defines you shouldn’t indent the body further: the `(i y ...)` should be at the same indent level as the previous line.